# Mostrar errores con BootStrap

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, bootstrap, netbeans

Como ven así quiero lograr que aparezca.
[image]

Este es mi proyecto, como ven el error debería de aparecer si el usuario intenta introducir como nombre menos de 6 caracteres o mas de 24.
[image]

Aquí ya presione el botón enviar datos y solo se recarga la pagina sin mostrar nada
[image]

Al darle al botón enviar datos en vez de que me aparezca el error solo se actualiza y carga el formulario vació. Ya he revisado el código varias veces pero no encuentro el error.
Agradezco si alguien me dice como solucionarlo o que parte del código debería revisar.

No pego todo el código ya que es demasiado pero dejo el link de el proyecto si alguien quiere revisarlo.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/13q34Tdt7r_ei41EJyVjnbjA3Rs8ss2bE/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

por lo que me contas me suena que estas usando un `form` que tiene un `action='alguna/funcion/dentro'` y hay un `button` que es de tipo `type='submit'`

cuando haces click en el boton el formulario se reenvia y con eso la pagina se recarga porque es como que alguien escribiera en la barra de navegacion 'https://miprograma.com' y diera enter, con lo que la pagina se recarga por lo que no se muestra el error con bootstrap porque la pagina se aca de dibujar de nuevo.

lo que tenes que hacer para que no pase es hacer un llamada asincronica con ajax, jquery te lo permite hacer muy facil(hay otras formas) , de esa manera te quedas en la misma pagina y se muestra el error